# Play .mxf files in browser (chrome, Firefox, Edge, ect.)

Tags: html, video, browser

I am trying to create a website that should display videos stored on a server accessable trough a database.
The videos are storaged as .mxf files and are quite large and high quality.

I am not able to convert the files to MP4 which would solve the issue since i could use HTML5 video to display them.

I need to be able to pause/play, jump to different parts of the videos, change volume and all that as well.

I have tried to find a player that allows me to do this for some time now but have not found one. Does any body know if there is a player that requires no installation client side and can play the .mxf files in browser? Or if there is any way i can create the functionallity myself?

Comment: there doesn't appear to be an existing javascript based .mxf player, though potentially one could be built using HTML5 EME capabilities (not a trivial task). why can't you transcode the assets?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for slow answer. I cannot transcode the files since i do not have the possibility to store two versions of the files and i need the original versions for other use (there might be a way around this but i have not found it). I will look into HTML5 EME though, Thanks for answer!

Comment: I'd like to revive this! Has anyone found a solution to this?